# Core Data coexistence with network service for the "What if the user cannot connect?" situation

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, core-data, database-design, icloud

I am looking for the proper way for a swift iOS app that relies on, in my case: AWS but has a local persistent data store so that every possible feature of the app can be used offline.

So far, I went from a pillar or two of Core Data to a full core data stack and it is becoming difficult to foresee how to coexist with AWS DynamoDB. While DynamoDB is of a NoSQL structure, Core Data in the way I have set it up is that of a SQLite persistent data store.

I need to eventually download tables and primarily use AWS for most situations where users are online, but if they want to work offline, I need to be prepared. Perhaps I should try to create a singular User entity, because why would I want to store other users offline? Then once internet is active, I could try to push it to my DynamoDB Users (plural) table.

I have created Entity's in Core Data such as Users, Authors, Profile.

In the scenario a user opens the app and has no internet access, I am planning on inserting a Users entity and my goal is to correctly populate Authors and Profile, because this offline end user is definitely a User, and I want to setup at least a Profile for them as well so that they can later tweak with customizations.

I have maybe too many relationships. I want to do this correct.

In simple situations, I understand a Person Entity might have a father, mother, child and how they can all fit nicely into Person, but since I have entities with enough unique attributes that I thought I need to create their own entities,

How should I go about creating an entity that certainly makes a User/Users record and establishes a Profile?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is this:

Core Data is your local cache whether you are offline or online.  If you are online then the app should refresh the Core Data cache when appropriate.

When offline the app should not update the cache.

The User Interface in either case is identical.  The user interface feeds from the Core Data cache ONLY.

I suggest watching my talk on MVC-N that is hosted by [realm.io](https://realm.io/news/slug-marcus-zarra-exploring-mvcn-swift/).